# How to run Robot Framework test cases in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, robotframework

I had to write my test cases in Robot Framework now I would like to run these test cases in JMeter.

I saw that exist the Jmeter library but this is to execute JMeter tests inside the robot right? I need to do the opposite, run the Robot Framework inside JMeter.

I had a test case like this, how to run in Jmeter? I need to use chrome options....

```
    *** Test Cases ***
    ${chrome_options} =     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
    &{SiteOptions}         Create Dictionary    last_used=${1470931206}     setting=${1}
    &{media_stream_mic}    Create Dictionary    ${url},*=${SiteOptions}
    ${prefs}               Create Dictionary    profile.content_settings.exceptions.media_stream_mic=${media_stream_mic}    profile.content_settings.exceptions.media_stream_camera=${media_stream_mic}
    Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_experimental_option    prefs    ${prefs}
    Create WebDriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}
    Go To    ${url}
    Do some actions....
```

Someone know if is possible and how to do?

Answer (score 1):

2 Options:

1) Take a look at the nice testframework [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/kb/Index/) with this you can run JMeter and Robot Framework together

2) Create an bat, powershell with the Robot Framework test and call it via the [OS Proces Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter)

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look at https://kowalpy.github.io/Robot-Framework-JMeter-Library/ Seems, it can do execution and also report converting to robot framework style/format.